# Emergency mode during fsck

Tags: 20.04

I recently upgraded to Ubuntu 20.04 on my machine and everything was fine.But after opening windows(not the first time) and switching back to Ubuntu it starts a fsck which at 32% goes into emergency mode and it comes back to emergence mode even after hitting <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> See below:

```
/dev/sda4: recovering journal
/dev/sda4: clean, 521649/2886128 files, 5537425/11553792 blocks
You are in emergency mode.  After logging in, type "journalctl -xb" to view system logs, "systemctl reboot" to reboot, "systemctl default" or "exit to boot into default mode.
Press Enter for maintenance
(or press Control-D to continue):
Reloading system manager configuration
Starting default target
You are in emergency mode.  After logging in, type "journalctl -xb" to view system logs, "systemctl reboot" to reboot, "systemctl default" or "exit to boot into default mode.
Press Enter for maintenance

Reloading system manager configuration
Starting default target
You are in emergency mode.  After logging in, type "journalctl -xb" to view system logs, "systemctl reboot" to reboot, "systemctl default" or "exit to boot into default mode.
Press Enter for maintenance
```

Comment: In Windows, have you installed any drivers that allow you to read/write to Linux ext2/3/4 partitions? Start comments to me with @heynnema or I'll miss them.

Comment: Rather than CTRL-D, just hit ENTER, then type `journalctl -xb` and take a screenshot and edit it into your question. Start comments to me with @heynnema or I'll miss them.

Answer (score 1):

Let's manually check your file system...

- boot to a Ubuntu Live DVD/USB in “Try Ubuntu” mode
- open a `terminal` window by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>
- type `sudo fdisk -l`
- identify the /dev/sdXX device name for your "Linux Filesystem"
- type `sudo fsck -f /dev/sda4`, replacing `sdXX` with the number you found earlier
- repeat the `fsck` command if there were errors
- type `reboot`

Comment: I got it I ran fsck on all the partitions manually from the emergency mode itself and it got resolved

Comment: @heavilyashamed Please remember to accept my answer by clicking on the checkmark icon that appears just to the left of my answer. Thanks!

Comment: @heavilyashamed Status please...

Answer (score 0):

You can also edit /etc/fstab and use *noauto* option instead of *defaults*.
This will disable auto mounting of not connected disks